# Magento 2: get next and previous link product links on product page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have attempted to get the below helper class to function properly when called, however it returns the current product link rather than the previous and next links as it's intended. Also what would the proper way to filter products marked not visible. Any help is appreciated.

**Helper Class**

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;   
    protected $productRepository; 
     public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

         )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
  public function getNextProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public function getPreviousProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return false;

    }
}
```

**Call within breadcrumbs.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->getRequest()->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') : ?>
    <a href="<?php $this->helper('Name\Module\Helper\Data')->getPreviousProduct() ?>">Previous</a>
    <a href="<?php $this->helper('Name\Module\Helper\Data')->getNextProduct() ?>">Next</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like your code executing `return false;` even if your condition is `true`. Please add it in else statement.

```
<?php
namespace Name\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_coreRegistry;   
    protected $productRepository; 
    public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
            \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository

         )
        {
            $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getNextProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }else{
                return false;    
            }
        }else{
            return false;    
        }
    }

    public function getPreviousProduct()
    {
        $prodId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_product')->getId();

        $catArray = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_category');

        if($catArray){
            $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
            $keys = array_flip(array_keys($catArray));
            $values = array_keys($catArray);

            $productId = $values[$keys[$prodId]-1];

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            if($product->getId()){
               return $product->getProductUrl();
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Same issue occurs.

Comment: did you check your `$prodId` (current product id) and `$productId` are different???